# phone doesn't boot after installing launcher

Tags: boot, launcher

I just installed [Turbo Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cooeeui.brand.turbolauncher) on my android device. When i activated it, my screen was black. I couldn't do anything. I thought rebooting could fix it, so i rebooted my phone.
But... my phone doesn't even start anymore! It's just staying on my loading screen. Nothing happens, it's just starting up forever.
This happened about an hour ago, and my phone is still starting up! I think it will never start again! I also can't turn my phone off anymore (because it's starting up)

So my question: what can i do about it? Is there a way to reset my phone or something?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What model device do you have and what version of android?

Comment: [alcatel one touch m'pop](http://www.gsmarena.com/alcatel_one_touch_m_pop-5242.php) with android 4.1 jellybean @Goblinlord

Comment: I wrote up some basic instructions in an answer.  Try them out.  You should be able to remove the newly installed APK via recovery.  Let me know if you need more instruction/help with this though.  Using ADB without ever done anything like it before could be daunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user40849, i managed to solve this problem. His answer is not very detailed, so i'll give a complete answer.

First, you need to reboot in safe mode. you can accomplish this by starting up your phone and then holding the volume up and down button at the same time untill the phone is started. You should see the words 'safe mode' in the bottom left corner of your phone.

When you are in safe mode, you can't see 3rd party apps in the list of all apps.
To remove the laucher, you have two options:

Remove the launcher in the settings:  Settings > Apps > Turbo Laucher > Delete

or remove it via google play:  My Apps > Turbo Launcher > Delete

Now just reboot your device normally, so you're back in normal mode, and the laucher is deleted!

Answer (score 0):

Reboot in safe mode. Once in you should be able to delete the launcher.

Comment: And how can i do that? I don't know how i can run in safe mode in android

Comment: @JoJo Turn on your phone. While turning on press multiple times the menu button (not the home button) until it powers up. You shoul see in the bottom left the words 'safe mode'. It will launch your stock launcher

Comment: If you phone does not have a physical menu button then, power on and when you see the logo, press and hold the Volume Down button. Hold it until you see "Safe Mode" in the lower-left corner of the screen.

Comment: This worked! +1. Only the answer is not very detailed, so i'll write a new answer that is. still thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Android SDK on a PC so you can use ADB.
2. Install ADB drivers as necessary.
3. Boot into recovery by holding 'Vol +' and 'Power' until it boots into recovery.
4. At the command prompt run `adb devices` while it is stuck loading.
5. Once your device shows up run:

   adb shell

   adb rm /data/app/com.cooeeui.brand.turbolauncher1.apk
6. Reboot your device.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting if anybody needed it in future.
I had the same problem once. but I could access the notification drawer. and I had a battery booster installed. So , I clicked it and clicked the rating button. It went directly to Google play and there I could uninstall from the launcher's details page.